# How to store arrays inside array of pointers

Tags: c

i'm trying to implement little program that takes a text and breaks it into lines and sort them in alphabetical order but i encountered a little problem, so i have *readlines* function which updates an array of pointers called *lines*, the problem is when i try to printf the first pointer in *lines* as an array using **%s** nothing is printed and there is no errors.

I have used *strcpy* to copy an every single text line(local char array) into a pointer variable and then store that pointer in *lines* array but it gave me the error.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINES 4
#define MAXLENGTH 1000

char *lines[MAXLINES];

void readlines() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAXLINES; i++) {
        char c, line[MAXLENGTH]; 
        int j;
 
        for (j = 0; (c = getchar()) != '\0' && c != '\n' && j < MAXLENGTH; j++) {
            line[j] = c;
        }

        lines[i] = line;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    readlines();
    printf("%s", lines[0]);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you've allocated space for the strings that `lines` will point to.

Comment: Maybe if you had declared `char lines[MAX_LINES][MAX_LENGTH]`.

Comment: Your `line` array is being recreated at the top of the loop... You want either @Chris's suggestion, or to `malloc()` a new buffer, or to use `strdup()` to copy the input of each line... (Don't forget to `free()` anything `malloc()`'d AND always allocate the extra byte for the `'\0'` at the end of each string... You are not terminating your strings, you know!)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes the exact input required to reproduce the problem. Please also specify the desired output and the actual output. The statement "but it gave me the error" is not a sufficient description of the problem.

Comment: What happens to the `line` array when `readlines()` returns? (hint: it is no longer valid). What does that leave `lines[x]` pointing to?

Comment: I added an example on a way to use arrays of pointers, arrays of arbitrary size. And a note on why your code does not work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for malloc(), free(), exit()
#include <string.h> // for strcpy()

#define MAXLINES 4
#define MAXLENGTH 1000
char *lines[MAXLINES];

void readlines() {
    for( int i = 0; i < MAXLINES; i++) {
        char c, line[MAXLENGTH + 1]; // ALWAYS one extra to allow for '\0'
        int j = 0; 

        // RE-USE(!) local array for input characters until NL or length
        // NB: Casting return value to character (suppress warning)
        while( (c = (char)getchar()) != '\0' && c != '\n' && j < MAXLENGTH )
            line[ j++ ] = c;

        line[j] = '\0'; // terminate array (transforming it to 'string')

        // Attempt to get a buffer to preserve this line
        // (Old) compiler insists on casting return from malloc()
        if( ( lines[i] = (char*)malloc( (j + 1) * sizeof lines[0][0] ) ) == NULL ) {
            fprintf( stderr, "malloc failure\n" );
            exit( -1 );
        }
        strcpy( lines[i], line ); // preserve this line
    }
}

int my_main() {

    readlines(); // only returns after successfully reading 4 lines of input

    for( int i = 0; i < MAXLINES; i++)
        printf( "Line %d: '%s'\n", i, lines[i] ); // enhanced

    /* Maybe do stuff here */

    for( int j = 0; j < MAXLINES; j++) // free up allocated memory.
        free( lines[j] );

    return 0;
}
```

If you would prefer to 'factor out` some code (and have a facility that you've written is absent, here's a version:

```
char *my_strdup( char *str ) {
    int len = strlen( str )  + 1; // ALWAYS +1

    // Attempt to get a buffer to preserve this line
    // (Old) compiler insists on casting return from malloc()
    char *pRet = (char*)malloc( len * sizeof *pRet );

    if( pRet == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "malloc failure\n" );
        exit( -1 );
    }
    return strcpy( pRet, str );
}
```

The the terminating and preserve is condensed to:

```
    line[j] = '\0'; // terminate array (transforming it to 'string')
    lines[i] = my_strdup( line ); // preserve this line
```

Comment: can you elaborate, why do i need stdup function (by the way it's unavailable) and why my code does not work?

Comment: @aymanbenyahia: The function [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strdup) will probably be part of the upcoming ISO C23 standard, but it is not part of the ISO C18 current standard. That is probably why the function `strdup` is not yet available with you. I believe most compilers already support this function, but not all.

Comment: Nor is is part of the `C11` standard. It is part of `POSIX.1-2001`. You already have `j` (length), just as easy to do `lines[0] = malloc (j+1); memcpy (lines[0], lines, j+1);` (don't forget to check the return of `mailloc` (e.g. `if (lines[0] == NULL)` and handle the error)

Comment: @aymanbenyahia I'd posted a comment below your OP explaining that `line[ ]` is being refilled on each iteration. If you want to store 'n' separate lines, you need 'n' separate buffers to hold each. In response to other comments, I've added more code and commentary to this answer. (Also using 'malloc()' since you report 'strdup()' is not available in your library of 'standard' functions.

Comment: @aymanbenyahia Just added a bit more 'technique' to the answer... :-)

Answer (score 3):

One problem is the following line:

```
lines[i] = line;
```

In this line, you make `lines[i]` point to `line`. However, `line` is a local `char` array whose [lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/lifetime) ends as soon as the current loop iteration ends. Therefore, `lines[i]` will contain a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) (i.e. a pointer to an object that is no longer valid) as soon as the loop iteration ends.

For this reason, when you later call

```
printf("%s", lines[0]);
```

`lines[0]` is pointing to an object whose lifetime has ended. Dereferencing such a pointer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Therefore, you cannot rely on getting any meaningful output, and your program may crash.

One way to fix this would be to not make `lines` an array of pointers, but rather an multidimensional array of `char`, i.e. an array of strings:

```
char lines[MAXLINES][MAXLENGTH+1];
```

Now you have a proper place for storing the strings, and you no longer need the local array `line` in the function `readlines`.

Another issue is that the line

```
printf("%s", lines[0]);
```

requires that `lines[0]` points to a string, i.e. to an array of characters terminated by a null character. However, you did not put a null character at the end of the string.

After fixing all of the issues mentioned above, your code should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINES 4
#define MAXLENGTH 1000

char lines[MAXLINES][MAXLENGTH+1];

void readlines() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAXLINES; i++) {
        char c; 
        int j;
 
        for (j = 0; (c = getchar()) != '\0' && c != '\n' && j < MAXLENGTH; j++) {
            lines[i][j] = c;
        }

        //add terminating null character
        lines[i][j] = '\0';
    }
}

int main(void) {
    readlines();
    printf("%s", lines[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

However, this code still has a few issues, which are probably unrelated to your immediate problem, but could cause trouble later:

1. The function `getchar` will return `EOF`, not `'\0'`, when there is no more data (or when an error occurred). Therefore, you should compare the return value of `getchar` with `EOF` instead of `'\0'`. However, a `char` is not guaranteed to be able to store the value of `EOF`. Therefore, you should store the return value of `getchar` in an `int` instead. Note that `getchar` returns a value of type `int`, not `char`.
2. When `j` reaches `MAX_LENGTH`, you will call `getchar` one additional time before terminating the loop. This can cause undesired behavior, such as your program waiting for more user input or an important character being discarded from the input stream.

In order to also fix these issues, I recommend the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINES 4
#define MAXLENGTH 1000

char lines[MAXLINES][MAXLENGTH+1];

void readlines() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAXLINES; i++)
    {
        //changed type from "char" to "int"
        int c;

        int j;

        for ( j = 0; j < MAXLENGTH; j++ )
        {
            if ( (c = getchar()) == EOF || c == '\n' )
                break;

            lines[i][j] = c;
        }

        //add terminating null character
        lines[i][j] = '\0';
    }
}

int main(void) {
    readlines();
    printf("%s", lines[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better than OP's code, yet `getchar()` may return `EOF` and is not accounted for. `char c;` should be `int c;` to handle the 257 different responses of `getchar()`.  `j < MAXLENGTH` should be the first test, not last, else `c` is lost. Off-by-one - use `char lines[MAXLINES][MAXLENGTH + 1];` to avoid buffer overflow.

Comment: @chux: Thanks for poiting out these issues. I believe I have addressed all three of them in the last code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem 1

```
char *lines[MAXLINES];
```

For the compiler it makes no difference how you write this, but for you, as you are learning C, maybe it is worth consider different spacing and naming. Question is: what is `lines[]`? `lines[]` is supposed to be an array of strings and hold some text inside. So `lines[0]` is a string, `lines[1]` is a string and so on. As pointed in a comment you could also use `char lines[MAX_LINES][MAX_LENGTH]` and have a 2D box of NxM `char`. This way you would have a pre-determined size in terms of number and size of lines and have simpler things at a cost of wasting space in lines of less than `MAX_LENGTH` chars and having a fixed number of lines you can use, but no need to allocate memory.
A more flexible way is to use an array of pointers. Since each pointer will represent a line, a single one

```
        char* line[MAXLINES];
```

is a better picture of the use: `line[0]` is `char*`, `line[1]` is `char*` and so on.  But you will need to allocate memory for each line **(and you did not)** in your code.

Remember `int main(int argc, char**argv)`
This is the most flexible way, since in this way you can hold any number of lines. The cost? Additional allocations.

```
    size_t n_lines;
    char** line;
```

This may be the best representation, as known by every C program since `K&R`.

#### Problem 2

```
  for (
    j = 0;
    (c = getchar()) != '\0' && c != '\n' && j < MAXLENGTH;
    j++) {
       line[j] = c;
        }
    lines[i] = line;
```

This loop does not copy the final `0` that terminates each string. And reuses the same `line`, a `char[]` to hold the data as being read. And the final line does not copy a string, if one existed there. There is no one since the final `0` was stripped off by the loop. And there is no data too, since the area is being reused.

#### A complete C example of *`uploading`* a file to a container in memory

I will let an example of a more controlled way of writing this, a *container* for a set of lines and even a sorting function.

#### a data structure

The plan is to build an array of pointers as the system does for `main`. Since we do no know ahead the number of lines and do not want this limitation we will allocate memory in groups of `blk_size` lines. At any time we have `limit` pointers to use. From these `size` are in use. `line[]` is `char*` and points to a single line of text. The `struct` is

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t blk_size;  // block
    size_t limit;     // actual allocated size
    size_t size;      // size in use
    char** line;      // the lines

}   Block;
```

#### the test function

```
Block* load_file(const char*);
```

Plan is to call `load_file("x.txt")` and the function returns a `Block*` pointing to the array representing the lines in file, one by one. Then we call `qsort()` and sort the whole thing. If the program is called `lines` we will run

```
    lines x.txt
```

and it will load the file `x.txt`, show its contents on screen, sort it, show the sorted lines and then erase everything at exit.

#### `main()` for the test

```
int    main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char msg[80] = {0};
    if (argc < 2) usage();
    Block* test = load_file(argv[1]);
    sprintf(msg, "==> Loading \"%s\" into memory", argv[1]);    
    status_blk(test, msg);
    qsort(test->line, test->size, sizeof(void*), cmp_line);
    sprintf(msg, "==> \"%s\" after sort", argv[1]);
    status_blk(test, msg);
    test = delete_blk(test);
    return 0;
};
```

As planned

- `load_file()` is the `constructor` and load the file contents into a `Block`.
- `status_blk()` shows the contents and accepts a convenient optional message
- `qsort()` sorts the lines using a one-line `cmp_line()` function.
- `status_blk()` is called again and shows the now sorted contents
- as in `C++` `delete_blk()` is the `destructor` and erases the whole thing._

#### output using `main()` as `tlines.c` for testing

```
PS M:\> .\lines tlines.c
loading "tlines.c" into memory
Block extended for a total of 16 pointers


==> Loading "tlines.c" into memory
Status: 13 of 16 lines. [block size is 8]:
   1    int main(int argc, char** argv)
   2    {
   3        char msg[80] = {0};
   4        if (argc < 2) usage();
   5        Block* test = load_file(argv[1]);
   6        sprintf(msg, "==> Loading \"%s\" into memory", argv[1]);
   7        status_blk(test, msg);
   8        qsort(test->line, test->size, sizeof(void*), cmp_line);
   9        sprintf(msg, "==> \"%s\" after sort", argv[1]);
  10        status_blk(test, msg);
  11        test = delete_blk(test);
  12        return 0;
  13    };

==> "tlines.c" after sort
Status: 13 of 16 lines. [block size is 8]:
   1        Block* test = load_file(argv[1]);
   2        char msg[80] = {0};
   3        if (argc < 2) usage();
   4        qsort(test->line, test->size, sizeof(void*), cmp_line);
   5        return 0;
   6        sprintf(msg, "==> Loading \"%s\" into memory", argv[1]);
   7        sprintf(msg, "==> \"%s\" after sort", argv[1]);
   8        status_blk(test, msg);
   9        status_blk(test, msg);
  10        test = delete_blk(test);
  11    int main(int argc, char** argv)
  12    {
  13    };
```

#### About the code

I am not sure if it needs much explanation, it is a single function that does the file loading and it has around 20 lines of code. The other functions has less than 10. The whole file is represented in `line` that is `char**` and `Block` has the needed info about actual size.

Since `line[]` is an array of pointers we can call

```
        qsort(test->line, test->size, sizeof(void*), cmp_line);
```

and use

```
int cmp_line(const void* one, const void* other)
{
    return strcmp(
        *((const char**)one), *((const char**)other));
}
```

using `strcmp()` to compare the strings and have the lines sorted.

- `create_blk()` accepts a block size for use in the calls to `realloc()` for eficiency.
- Delete a `Block` is a 3-step `free()` in the reverse order of allocation.

#### The complete code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    size_t blk_size;  // block
    size_t limit;     // actual allocated size
    size_t size;      // size in use
    char** line;      // the lines

}   Block;

Block* create_blk(size_t);
Block* delete_blk(Block*);
int    status_blk(Block*, const char*);


Block* load_file(const char*);
int    cmp_line(const void*, const void*);
void   usage();

int    main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char msg[80] = {0};
    if (argc < 2) usage();
    Block* test = load_file(argv[1]); 
    sprintf(msg, "\n\n==> Loading \"%s\" into memory", argv[1]);    
    status_blk(test, msg);
    qsort(test->line, test->size, sizeof(void*), cmp_line);
    sprintf(msg, "\n\n==> \"%s\" after sort", argv[1]);
    status_blk(test, msg);
    test = delete_blk(test);
    return 0;
};

int cmp_line(const void* one, const void* other)
{
    return strcmp(
        *((const char**)one), *((const char**)other));
}

Block* create_blk(size_t size)
{
    Block* nb = (Block*)malloc(sizeof(Block));
    if (nb == NULL) return NULL;
    nb->blk_size = size;
    nb->limit    = size;
    nb->size     = 0;
    nb->line     = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * size);
    return nb;
}

Block* delete_blk(Block* blk)
{
    if (blk == NULL) return NULL;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < blk->size; i += 1)
        free(blk->line[i]);  // free lines
    free(blk->line);         // free block
    free(blk);               // free struct
    return NULL;
}

int status_blk(Block* bl,const char* msg)
{
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s\n", msg);
    if (bl == NULL)
    {
        printf("Status: not allocated\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf(
        "Status: %zd of %zd lines. [block size is %zd]:\n",
        bl->size, bl->limit, bl->blk_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < bl->size; i += 1)
        printf("%4d\t%s", 1 + i, bl->line[i]);
    return 0;
}

Block* load_file(const char* f_name)
{
    if (f_name == NULL) return NULL;
    fprintf(stderr, "loading \"%s\" into memory\n", f_name);
    FILE* F = fopen(f_name, "r");
    if (F == NULL) return NULL;
    // file is open
    Block* nb = create_blk(8); // block size is 8
    char   line[200];
    char*  p = &line[0];
    p        = fgets(p, sizeof(line), F);
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        // is block full?
        if (nb->size >= nb->limit)
        {
            const size_t new_sz = nb->limit + nb->blk_size;
            char*        new_block =
                realloc(nb->line, (new_sz * sizeof(char*)));
            if (new_block == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(
                    stderr,
                    "\tCould not extend block to %zd "
                    "lines\n",
                    new_sz);
                break;
            }
            printf(
                "Block extended for a total of %zd "
                "pointers\n",
                new_sz);
            nb->limit = new_sz;
            nb->line  = (char**)new_block;
        }
        // now copy the line
        nb->line[nb->size] = (char*)malloc(1 + strlen(p));
        strcpy(nb->line[nb->size], p);
        nb->size += 1;
        // read next line
        p = fgets(p, sizeof(line), F);
    };  // while()
    fclose(F);
    return nb;
}

void usage()
{ 
    fprintf(stderr,"Use: program file_to_load\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```